# Closed Figures Made Up of Unit Squares

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polyomino

This is my first question.

I am wondering if there is a formula to find the number of non-congruent figures of area **n** that are made up of 1 by 1 non-overlapping squares, in which any square must share a common side with a square touching it?

For example, the number of these figures of area 1 is 1

The number of these figures of area 2 is 1

The number of these figures of area 3 is 2

Can this be generalized for a formula?

Comment: See the Wikipedia ["polyomino" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino). There is no known formula, but computer searches have enumerated "fixed" polyominoes up to $n=56$ (the count being $6.915\times 10^{31}$) and "free" polyominoes up to $n=28$